# MVYSideMenu pop to root viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, menu, mvysidemenu

I am using [MVYSideMenu](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu) in my application and I can present new controller using "changeContentViewController" of MVYSideMenu but it presents new controller so from here I want to pop back to my root(HomeViewController) so I have done lot of research on this but couldn't find solution.

So if anybody knows the solution please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MVYSideMenu](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu) is making `rootViewController`, when you are trying to open any view from this. If you are making `rootViewController`, then you can not able to `pop` from that.

So if you want to go back, then you have to `Push` that view instead of making rootViewController.

I think, Right Now you are using following code for open any controller for side menu:

```
ChildViewController *contentVC = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
appDelegate.nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contentVC];
appDelegate.nav.navigationBarHidden=TRUE;
[[self sideMenuController] changeContentViewController:appDelegate.nav closeMenu:YES];
```

So Please use following code instead of above code. Here nav is object of `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate`.

```
ChildViewController *contentVC = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
[appDelegate.nav pushViewController:contentVC animated:YES];
[[self sideMenuController] changeContentViewController:appDelegate.nav closeMenu:YES];
```

So You can able to push any view from side menu. And Now just try to pop this view. I am sure that you can able to pop this view after using this.

Make sure that, If you do this, then may be memory leakage is there. Because all times viewControllers are adding to the navigation controller. So My suggestion is, don't do this, if you can convince your client. :) Otherwise, you have to make your own side menu.

**EDIT :-**

Yes we can able to enable / disable side menu for some view controllers. Please add following methods into **MVYSideMenuController.m** file. And call this method from `viewWillAppear` of your viewControllers.

```
- (void)addGestures {

    if (!_panGesture) {
        _panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
        [_panGesture setDelegate:self];
     //   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_panGesture];
    }

    if (!_tapGesture) {
        _tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
        [_tapGesture setDelegate:self];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
    }
}

- (void)removeGestures{
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:_panGesture];
    _panGesture = nil;
}
```

You can easily call this methods `LocalNotifications`. May be `addGestures` already there. You can remove gestures by calling `removeGestures` method when you needed in your controller. But do not forgot to `addGestures` when you needed side menu after removing gestures.

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But I want to popback from the child view controller.
So if you know any other drawer which works like same as MVYSideDrawer please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Just because When I am showing any ChildViewController from My Side menu I want a pop option (back button) to go back to the root view controller and it looks like it is not possible using MVYSideMenu.

Comment: It is possible. I do this into my app and it works. Just use my code into your project. Otherwise update your question with your code. So I can able to see what happens when you are trying this.

Comment: thank you for solution.
I have one last question pls is it possible to disable the side view controller for some viewcontroller.

Comment: Yes we can able do this easily. Please see my updated answer for this.